# Signal buffer/converter/recorder

Tags: digital-logic, signal, i2c

Is there an IC that will "record" a digital signal received (highs and lows) record or buffer that input, and finally send to another IC thru I2C interface.

The problem is that I have two different clocks and the receiving IC is not able to get signal because it is too fast.

UPDATE:
Thanks for the answers.

Chip sending data works at speed at least 256Mhz, chip receiving data - 48Mhz.
Communication protocol looks like that:

http://i39.tinypic.com/2gv7ts3.png

Comment: Are you saying the final device is too fast to directly connect to the input? Can you tell us speeds of input and required speed of output to receiving device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's called a FIFO. Commonly used to mesh up two different clock domains. There are not a lot of [I2C options](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3108.pdf). But you'd do well searching for a [UART to I2C converter](http://www.nxp.com/products/interface_and_connectivity/bridges/uart_to_i2c_master_gpio_bridges/).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is the wrong question for the problem - you should really look at making the data clock run at an acceptable rate for both devices. If you can't read data faster than ~48MHz then there's no point clocking it out at 256MHz - either adjust the clocks or change the software to send more slowly.

Most I2C/SPI style comms is moving relatively small amounts of data at relatively low speed, usually under 1MHz. If you have serious amounts to move, it's perhaps better to look at parallel data lines rather than ramping the clock rate up. Running slower clocks makes board design easier and the system more tolerant, and avoids RFI/EMI headaches.

You could also look at (google) flow control, handshaking, signalling, clock stretching, master/slave arrangements, etc. - this problem has been around for ages in all electronics and has been solved in various ways by minds greater than ours.